# QR report of size A5 to be repeated on an A4 paper sheet

Tags: quickreports

BDS2006, QR4.

I have an A5 size report and I want(well, the customer does :)) to print it twice on an A4 paper sheet. This is because they need to cut the two halves and keep one "for the record" while handing out the other one.

Anybody knows a trick to do this without having to add yet another repo?

Thank you!

Andrea

Comment: I would rather not answer my own question, but I have solved it at least for now. Better approaches would, however, be welcome.

What I did was using a composite report and simply add my own report twice :) This works and does not appear to have counterindications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will post the answer since no one has come up with a better idea... yet!
What I had to do is using a composite report and then just adding the reports on the AddReports event.

I added two times the same report and QR didn't complain.

Last, just use the preview to see it on screen et voila'!

Andrea